# Removing twitter bootstrap login modal background

Tags: html, css, twitter, authentication, modal-dialog

so I'm trying to insert my login form using a modal and so far it worked. Only problem is I want to remove the background outside the login form (as you can see in the picture). Because right now, it looks not good. Is it possible? Any other way to achieve this?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R671i.png)

Comment: Just put your login form inside this div.  < div id="login button id" class= "modal-dialog modal- sm" > put here you login form <\>

Comment: @AnilPanwar Don't put your answers in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your login form inside this div.               < div id="login button id" class= "modal-dialog modal- sm" > put here you login form <\div>